# Best practice categories and Tag at tx_news

Tags: typo3, tx-news

Can anyone bring closer the difference between categories and tags in tx_news to me? 
So far I have used only categories for the news section. for example, improve the internal filter by organizers or venue.
In the meantime about 130 categories have gathered.

How can I use meaningful tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to differ because it always depends as well on the use case as well but I will try.

**Categories**

> **Categories** are shown as a tree structure, therefore a category has
>   always a parent category (if it is not a root category) and categories
>   on the same level. Categories can be translated.

**Tags**

> **Tags** are not sorted at all. Tags can not be translated currently (patch pending).

**Example**

Imagine a news website with typical categories like *Sport*, *Web* and *Politics*. Those categories can have sub categories to get a tree like that

```
Sport
- Baseball
- Basketball
Web
- IT
- Trends
Politics
- Party 1
- Party 2
```

Tags can now be used to add additional information which can be then used later for filtering, creating landing pages, .... Those tags could be

- viral trend
- christmas
- winners

You could add as many tags as you want, just as hashtags you are used at twitter or facebook, instagram, ...